# Convert time into "h:mm:a" in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
MariaDB [supplier monitoring]> select time as "h:mm:a" from delivers;
```

I just wanna ask how I can I cast this time into "h:mm:a" like this 1:00pm

Comment: Use the `DATE_FORMAT()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a column of `time` datatype, you can use [`time_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format):

```
select time_format(mycol, '%h:%i %p') from delivers;
```

If the column is of `datetime` datatype, then you want [`date_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
select date_format(mycol, '%h:%i %p') from delivers;
```

Comment: like this "select time_format(mycol, %h:%i %p)  from delivers"